# how to #include<torch.extension.h> in a .cpp file with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

Now I'm working with a project requiring using Pytorch C++ extension.
I've installed a Pytorch of version 1.4.0 in a python virtual environment:

```
activate crfasrnn
>>>import torch
>>>print(torch.__version__)
1.4.0
```

I'm using visual studio as a C++ compiler.
The code is like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<torch/extension.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the compiler tells me "can not open 'torch/extension.h'"
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the appropriate LibTorch binaries from https://pytorch.org/ and then include the required binaries in the visual studio. 
You can follow the detailed instructions given [here](https://medium.com/@boonboontongbuasirilai/building-pytorch-c-integration-libtorch-with-ms-visual-studio-2017-44281f9921ea).